# How can I navigate inside a spreadsheet cell immediately after typing text?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

This seems like it's a blindingly simple question with an obvious answer yet I cannot figure out how to do it nor find solutions online.

If I type some text into a Google Sheets spreadsheet cell and make a typo, what is the least number of key presses to navigate back to the place where the typo is so I can edit it? For example: `this s some text`

Normally you would press <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>. However whenever you press left or right after immediately entering text in a cell it will navigate away from the current cell.

If the cell content is not new then you *can* navigate the text using normal text navigation shortcuts but needing to leave a cell and coming back adds more key presses.

I've tried different combinations of modifier  keys and cannot figure out how to navigate within a cell without first leaving. The quickest way I've found is to leave the cell and come back to it which adds at least 3-key presses (<kbd>←</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out the far quickest is to leave the cell with some arrow and then return. But also there is another way (however it depends on how and where exactly you want to return). Let's say you made a typo in **`xxxxaaxx`** (**`a`** instead of **`x`**), you are able to "return" only by mouse clicking into the overview field which is not always plausible especially when you don't wanna do that extra hand move.

And also is worth to mention the possibility of mouse clicking directly into **fx** field right where you need to. **fx** field/box can be extended beyond one row in case of long formulas.

Comment: Ha, that's a disappointing answer, but thanks. Going to leave the question open for a few days in case someone else answers. By the way pressing `Shift` + `←` still removes me from the cell. I tried with Chrome and Firefox and it behaves in the same way for both.